# Can the Sony A55 software-correct lens aberrations like the Panasonic GH2 does?

Tags: lens, chromatic-aberration, distortion

Panasonic GH2 automatically corrects lens geometric distortion and chromatic aberration. If I understand it right, it always applies this correction just after reading from the sensor — so the image displayed by EVF is distortion and aberration free, as are RAW shoot, and JPEGs. [More info on how GH cameras correct lens aberration is here](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/panasonicdmcgh1/page17.asp).

This in fact makes all supported lens aberrations free.

**Can Sony A55 do something similar ??** Technically it should be no problem, as it uses an EVF as the Panasonic GH2 does. The only thing that should matter is the installed software (and maybe the lens needs to provide some info to the camera).

Answer (score 1):

[No it does not](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/sony/slt_a55/review).

Good question though, in all my years of reviewing cameras I have never thought of listing what a camera does not do except for truly rare omissions (no tripod mount, no built-in flash, that's about it).

Comment: I would say it is a shame and great pity... Sony should include such feature as soon as possible. Panasonic and Olympus are taking advantage of it already: lenses are practically  aberration free even when superzoom like those 14-140 F4-5.6 Panasonic. And designers can improve other optical qualities of lenses too when they don't have to worry about higher aberrations too much (I bet this is also the case of 14-140 as other optical qualities are very good).

Comment: Guess Sony is just starting with SLDs which is why it works for Micro Four-Third cameras. As long as the previews (EVF and LCD) shows the view corrected for geometric distortion than it becomes usable. I had an SLR which did this as an option and I had to turn it off because on some lenses it changed the framing noticeable and would cut off things that were intentionally in the image. It also has to happen without slowing the camera, another of my camera potentially corrects for chromatic aberrations but it takes 2 extra seconds per shot.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, chromatic aberrations and vignetting could be removed without any significant impact on image quality but geometric distortion correction would dramatically damage pixel-level sharpness.

Comment: I don't mind if a camera applies such correction when it's producing JPEGs, but I would *never* buy one that did this to RAWs (and I'd put up with in on JPEGs primarily because I never use them). This is something I'd much rather handle after the fact (assuming I do it at all).

Comment: @Jerry - That is an interesting comment. Would you expect the EVF/LCD do show something different for RAW and JPEG mode? What about RAW+JPEG? You need to see the *right* version to be able to frame correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to show the modified version for JPEG, but the original for raw. At least as most people use it, raw+JPEG is basically raw with a JPEG preview, so I don't think I'd apply the processing to either. Alternatively, just include menu entries to turn them on and off as the user sees fit.